# "unable to locate package pulp" when trying to install pulp

Tags: 14.04

I want to install pulp so I did `sudo apt-get install pulp` but I am stuck with an error:

```
Unable to locate package pulp
```

So I did a search and I found a solution that uses `sudo apt-get update`. However, I still receive the same errors. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This is an English speaking website, please translate your question accordingly, so that all users may understand what you're saying. If you have troubles with English, you can of course get assistance of services like https://translate.google.com - bad English is still better than no English at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [python-pulp [image: Install python-pulp]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-pulp) package, by any chance? If so, you can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pulp
```

Comment: i still receive the same errors even i use sudo apt-get install python-pulp

Comment: Hmm, seems like the package isn't available for Trusty. You could try "sudo pip install pulp".